# Two-dimensional Map Java

Tags: java, matrix, hashmap

I need a data structure that I could store my information in a two dimensional way. For example imagine a table that contains user-item ratings. I need to store all ratings for all users. let's say, user u1. I need to store ratings for user u1 and u2 and u3 and all other users. But the problem is I also need too store all ratings for all items. For example I need to store ratings provided by all users for each item. So I need something like a map that for users the key is the user ID and the value is the set of ratings. I can do that easily. But my problem is how I can also store ratings for Items. for example a map that the key is the item ID and the value is the set of ratings provided be users for that Item. I wanted to upload a table but since I didn't have enough reputation I couldn't do that.So just imagine a table like a two dimensional matrix that rows are users and columns are items. Is there a data structure that can do that? Or I should build two different maps? maybe there is a better option than Map but Since I had to choose a title for my question I wrote map.

Thanks

Comment: I think many-to-many database relations solve this. Why do you need to implement that directly into java?

Comment: Could able to provide some example on this

Comment: Perhaps this: [Google Guava Collections API - BiMap](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas Because I need to do some data analysis with this data using java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) class from the free [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library

```
Table<Integer, String, Double> table = HashBasedTable.create();

table.put(1, "a", 2.0);
double v = table.get(1, "a"); // getting 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own version of an appropriate Table object. Mind you, using something provided by an existing library is good. But trying your own implementation will help you understand the issues involved better. So you can try to add "remove" methods etc. to my implementation to complete it.

I prefer keeping the data in a table rather than implementing the maps inside `User` and `Item`, because the table can enforce adding each new rating through both row and column. If you keep your maps separate in two independent objects, you won't be able to enforce this.

Note that while I return protective copies of the internal maps in `getCol` and `getRow`, I return the reference to the actual values, not copies thereof, so that you can change a user's rating (assuming you chose a mutable object for that) without changing the table structure. Also note that if your user and item objects are mutable and this affects their `equals` or `hashCode`, the table will behave unpredictably.

```
public class Table<K1, K2, V> {

    // Two maps allowing us to retrieve the value through the row or the
    // column key.
    private Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> rowMap;
    private Map<K2, Map<K1, V>> colMap;

    public Table() {
        rowMap = new HashMap<>();
        colMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Allows us to create a key for the row, and place it in the structure
     * while there are still no relations for it.
     *
     * @param key
     *            The key for which a new empty row will be created.
     */
    public void addEmptyRow(K1 key) {
        if (!rowMap.containsKey(key)) {
            rowMap.put(key, new HashMap<K2, V>());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows us to create a key for the column, and place it in the
     * structure while there are still no relations for it.
     * 
     * @param key
     *            The key for which a new empty column will be created.
     */
    public void addEmptyCol(K2 key) {
        if (!colMap.containsKey(key)) {
            colMap.put(key, new HashMap<K1, V>());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert a value into the table using the two keys.
     * 
     * @param rowKey
     *            Row key to access this value
     * @param colKey
     *            Column key to access this value
     * @param value
     *            The value to be associated with the above two keys.
     */
    public void put(K1 rowKey, K2 colKey, V value) {
        Map<K2, V> row;
        Map<K1, V> col;

        // Find the internal row. If there is no entry, create one.
        if (rowMap.containsKey(rowKey)) {
            row = rowMap.get(rowKey);
        } else {
            row = new HashMap<K2, V>();
            rowMap.put(rowKey, row);
        }

        // Find the internal column, If there is no entry, create one.
        if (colMap.containsKey(colKey)) {
            col = colMap.get(colKey);
        } else {
            col = new HashMap<K1, V>();
            colMap.put(colKey, col);
        }

        // Add the value to both row and column.
        row.put(colKey, value);
        col.put(rowKey, value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the value associated with the given row and column.
     * 
     * @param rowKey
     *            Row key to access the value
     * @param colKey
     *            Column key to access the value
     * @return Value in the given row and column. Null if mapping doesn't
     *         exist
     */

    public V get(K1 rowKey, K2 colKey) {
        Map<K2, V> row;
        row = rowMap.get(rowKey);
        if (row != null) {
            return row.get(colKey);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a map representing the row for the given key. The map contains
     * only column keys that actually have values in this row.
     * 
     * @param rowKey
     *            The key to the row in the table
     * @return Map representing the row. Null if there is no row with the
     *         given key.
     */
    public Map<K2, V> getRow(K1 rowKey) {
        // Note that we are returning a protective copy of the row. The user
        // cannot change the internal structure of the table, but is allowed
        // to change the value's state if it is mutable.
        if (rowMap.containsKey(rowKey)) {
            return new HashMap<>(rowMap.get(rowKey));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a map representing the column for the given key. The map contains
     * only row keys that actually have values in this column.
     * 
     * @param colKey
     *            The key to the column in the table.
     * @return Map representing the column. Null if there is no column with
     *         the given key.
     */
    public Map<K1, V> getCol(K2 colKey) {
        // Note that we are returning a protective copy of the column. The
        // user cannot change the internal structure.
        if (colMap.containsKey(colKey)) {
            return new HashMap<>(colMap.get(colKey));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a set of all the existing row keys.
     * 
     * @return A Set containing all the row keys. The set may be empty.
     */
    public Set<K1> getRowKeys() {
        return new HashSet(rowMap.keySet());
    }

    /**
     * Get a set of all the existing column keys.
     * 
     * @return A set containing all the column keys. The set may be empty.
     */
    public Set<K2> getColKeys() {
        return new HashSet(colMap.keySet());
    }
}
```

The reason that I have methods `addEmptyRow` and `addEmptyCol` is that I thought it may be redundant to keep a separate data structure for your users and items. Once you add them to the table like this, you can get them through the `getRowKeys` and `getColKeys` so there is no need to keep them separately unless you want to structure them in anything other than a `Set`.

Note that this Table works with the key's value - two keys which are `equals` equivalent are the same key, and you should design your User and Item objects accordingly.

With appropriate definitions of `User`, `Item` and `Rating`, you can do something like

```
    Table<User, Item, Rating> table = new Table<>();

    table.addEmptyCol(new Item("Television"));
    table.addEmptyCol(new Item("Sofa"));

    User user = new User("Anakin");
    Item item = new Item("Light Sabre");
    table.put(user, item, new Rating(5));

    Item item1 = new Item("Helmet");
    table.put(user, item1, new Rating(7));

    Rating rating = table.get(user, item);
    rating.setRating(rating.getRating() + 10);

    User user1 = new User("Obi-Wan");
    table.put(user1, item, new Rating(8));
    table.put(user1, new Item("Television"), new Rating(0));
```

And then query the table for a particular user like so:

```
    Map<Item, Rating> anakinsRatings = table.getRow(user);

    for (Map.Entry<Item, Rating> entry : anakinsRatings.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(user + " rated " + entry.getKey() + " as "
                + entry.getValue().getRating());
    }
```

Or display a list of ratings for all items like so:

```
    for (Item currItem : table.getColKeys()) {
        Map<User, Rating> itemMap = table.getCol(currItem);
        if (itemMap.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("There are currently no ratings for \""
                    + currItem
                    + "\"");
        } else {
            for (Map.Entry<User, Rating> entry : table.getCol(currItem).entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("\""
                        + currItem
                        + "\" has been rated "
                        + entry.getValue().getRating() + " by "
                        + entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, the implementation is not complete - there is no `toString` for the table, for example, no `remove`, `removeRow`, `removeCol`, `clear`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two one-many relationships. A user has (gives) many ratings and an item has many ratings; this gives a many-many relationship of users-items which is your problem. Why not simply model it as described:

```
public class Rating {
  private User ratedBy;
  private Item itemRated;

  public Item getItem() { return itemRated; }
}

public class User {
  private Set<Rating> allRatings = new HashSet<>();

  public Rating getRatingFor(Item item) {
      for(Rating rating: allRatings) {
          if(item.equals(rating.getItem()) {
              return rating;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
}

public class Item {
  private Set<Rating> allRatings = new HashSet<>();
}
```

... and getters/setters etc as required. You can then get ratings with:

```
User user1 = new User();
// ... do stuff to populate ratings
Rating itemRatingByUser = user1.getRatingFor(item);
```

Comment: Thanks. why did you use a class for User and Item? it seems that the class is just a set. So why don't you define this sets in the Rating calss?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to use a two dimensional key. 
Assuming the id for both user and item is of the same type, you can create a class that is just a holder for the id and the type of the key. (the type can be the class of User or Item if available or just an enum value). Make then the map have keys of this type. Of course each rating will be referenced at least twice (once for each type)

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you need is called a Table. A table has two keys and an object, and looks, more or less, like an excel table with the two key sets as columns and rows. Hence the name. There are a variety of Table implementations. I think its normal to use the Guava implementations now. An explanation of  [guava's table interface](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) is here.

The API for guava's table [is here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), and the implementation that you want, the HashBasedTable, [is here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html)